# access top window document from iframe

Tags: iframe

if this code is inside iframe

```
 var topWindow = window.top;
```

then object topWindow.document is not accessible

```
topWindow.document.getElementById("iframe_id")); // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

Are both the top window document and the page with the script on the same domain? You can't access content in a frame unless they are on the same domain.

This has actually been discussed in quite a bit of detail here. [[Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed/)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed/)

Comment: No, different domains. I just need to display a dialog window at the iframe position.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the problem you have is that frames (and that includes iFrames) are at the same level as "document" in the domain object model (DOM). It is inside the window and not the document. Instead of document you need to access the frames list called "frames" from the window itself.

Try this instead:

```
 topWindow.frames["nameOfIFrame"];
```

The frames list behaves like an array - using [] notation and having a length.

See [MDN documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames)