# Bypassing Frame buster

Tags: javascript, framebusting

I need to bypass or bust a frame buster, but I don't have a server that returns 204. The best solution that works (partially so far) is the one in https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/framebust.pdf on page 4 section C, onBeforeUnload – 204 Flushing.

It is discussed here ([Frame buster buster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149101/frame-buster-buster)) and here ([Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)) and the code is reproduced below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prevent_bust = 0  
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ }  
    setInterval(function() {  
      if (prevent_bust > 0) {  
        prevent_bust -= 2  
        window.top.location = 'http://example.org/page-which-responds-with-204'  
      }  
    }, 1)  
</script>
```

My problem is, I don't have a server that returns an HTTP status code 204 (and I cannot set one up). How do I get around this?

Comment: Politely ask the owner of the site in question to allow you to display their website in an `<iframe>`?

Comment: It may help to understand about frame busting restrictions https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive//OWASP_AppSec_Research_2010_Busting_Frame_Busting_by_Rydstedt.pdf

Comment: This document was fairly informative https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/framebust.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't set up your own server, you don't have many options aside from using a third party server. The obvious downside is that it's not under your control, so you can't control its availability.

A server whose purpose is to return various HTTP status codes will potentially be more reliable (as opposed to finding something random). You could use [httpstat.us](https://httpstat.us). The main page lists all the status codes and options it supports. The following will return HTTP 204: [httpstat.us/204](https://httpstat.us/204).