# How to gracefully handle iframe breaker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I understand that there is no way to kill the iframe breaker... However, I was wondering, is there a way to gracefully handling it.

So far, I managed to detect it before exiting, using `<body onunload="function();">`. I was wondering whether it is possible to prevent it from loading the iframe or force it to open in the new window, etc.

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, you *can* actually do what you really want to do, which is [bust the iframe buster](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/preventing-frame-busting-and-click-jacking-ui-redressing/). The technique lets you use onbeforeunload to switch the page back to yours, but indirectly, since the browsers are too smart to let you set the URL in onbeforeunload. So instead, onbeforeunload sets an indicator variable to mark that the URL has changed, and you periodically poll that variable using a setInterval routine established when your page loads. As long as you're polling fast enough to catch the variable change, you can jump in and change the page's URL yourself. The trick is to change it to a page that returns a 204, a special status which tells the browser to leave the current page alone.

That said, this is a cat-and-mouse game. Check out [Jeff Attwood's StackOverflow question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed), where he asks how to bust the above technique. Web pages can bust the buster buster by beating the poll interval; basically, they set the URL to point to a tiny page, and one that has already been cached. As soon as the URL changes to that page, it will load faster than the poll routine can jump in and notice that the indicator variable has changed.

It's not easy to prevent loading the frame in the first place. If you really wanted, you could have your server download the page and parse the Javascript to see if the iframe-busting technique is present. However, short of emulating a browser, you can only rely on basic pattern-matching and it would be easy for a page to bypass that. (e.g. use top["l"+"ocation"] instead of top.location).

A smarter technique would be to track which URLs were redirecting using Ajax requests back to the server. (e.g. if the iframe is still there after it has loaded, send an Ajax request back to your server). You can't 100% guarantee the accuracy of those requests, since they  come from the browser, but you can at least use them to build up a manual blacklist.

You also can't force the iframe to break out into another window.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [the sandbox attribute](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) introduced in HTML5 to prevent the iframe buster. Just don't include `allow-top-navigation` in the whitelist:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
src="foo.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about an embedded iframe setting top.location? There's no way to prevent that as far as I know.

If you're worried about the contents of an iframe doing something you don't want, you could consider sanitizing the contents of that frame and hosting it yourself. Obviously this is very tricky, but it's pretty much the only true solution. See [Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) for a project that does this. This limits what you can actually host of course (if the code you're hosting uses XHR you're outta luck, for instance).

Comment: So you are saying that for example...
<iframe src="www.google.com"></iframe>

If google has top.location, it will still load but preventing the top.location from running?

The iframe src link is assumed to come from external sites. So, when other sites try to top.location = "", it will be prevented. 

However, I'm not clear about Caja. Is it a server-based app?

Comment: Caja re-writes javascript to sanitize it and only allow it access to a subset of the DOM. One of the things the cajoled code is not allowed access to is 'top'.

This is a good solution when the author of the iframe you're embedding knows their content is going to be embedded, because you need some standards around what you'll expose to their code. A good example of this is Apache Shindig (http://incubator.apache.org/shindig/), which allows gadget embedding and cajoling.