# What does the javascript snippet mean?

Tags: javascript

```
if(self!=top){ window.open(self.location,'_top'); }
```

Can someone explain this?

**EDIT**

What does `self!=top` and `window.open(self.location,'_top')` mean respectively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will break out of a HTML frame and replace the top-level frame by the current page.

It's akin to clicking a link with `target="_top"` set which will throw away the complete frameset and replace it with the page that link points to. It's exactly what that code does by simply "opening a link" (in user terms; in JavaScript it takes the form of `window.open`) to the very same page we're seeing, but at the top level.

`self` in this respect is the page we're currently in. `top` is the top-level frame the browser is displaying. If the browser doesn't display a frameset, then `self == top` holds. If however, our page is framed, then they will be different.

So `self != top` detects if the page is displayed in a frame and `window.open` is, as noted before, just like clicking on a link with the `target` attribute set to `"_top"` (the second argument.

Answer (score 4):

[The old frame buster](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001277.html). [Be also afraid of the frame buster buster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed).

Answer (score 0):

It means "if I am loaded in a frame, i.e. not the top page, open a new window showing me"