# How to Stop Gmail from maximizing an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, gmail

I am trying to create a webpage with Gmail embedded in an iframe. However, Gmail has some javascript code that executes whenever it is loaded. I believe the following js code snippet is what causes Gmail to hijack the window and maximize itself, destroying my parent iframe:

```
if (top.location != self.location) {
  top.location = self.location.href;
}
```

Preferably, I am looking for a solution that works cross-browser (and does not involve greasemonkey, or some other browser-based hack). If jquery has some applicable function/plugin, that would be great.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to disable javascript in browser, but then you would need to run Gmail's HTML version.

Answer (score 1):

As the code Gmail uses is located in a  block it's hard to prevent it from running. There might be some useful insights in an article about [preventing frame-busting](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/preventing-frame-busting-and-click-jacking-ui-redressing/).

Answer (score 1):

There is an SO question by Jeff Atwood that addresses this (but kind of in reverse): [Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)