# How gmail open in iframe, and stop to redirect into parent page

Tags: javascript, iframe, gmail

I am using iframe to open any other page into my website
but when i use gmail then its redirect to my top page,
so how to stop gmail to redirect

Comment: Why on earth are you loading Gmail on your own page?

Comment: Seems like GMail has a special constraint that prevents it from being loaded in a frame.
Could you please give more insight on why you are trying to do this? There's probably a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Gmail has a frame buster script that prevents it from running inside a frame. You could try [busting the frame buster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed), but that may not work either depending on how google implements the frame buster.

Relevant: [How to Stop Gmail from maximizing an iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181439/how-to-stop-gmail-from-maximizing-an-iframe)