# How to implement a frame buster?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security

I'm searching for a guide that describes how to implement a working frame buster that also deals with people that dont have JS activated in their browser.

I read [this very good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997) but i'm absolutely not interested in any advice like "dont do that yourself" or "maybe try...". i want to see a paper, with a step to step guide explaining every "why" (without maybe's and wihtout guesses). Academic papers prefered.

Can anyone post the link to the de-facto holy-grail paper of doing that?

thanks,

Comment: That would be a very odd academic paper. That said, as Michael states, that's just now how the web works. A frame is just a viewport that requests a URI to display. Sans javascript, there really is no way for that 'page' to have any idea whether it's in a frame or not.

Comment: I think you are asking too much.

Comment: if it doesnt exists or isnt possible to implement (even not with, maybe flash) than "impossible" would be the right answer for this question (up-vote count will show me).

Comment: Flash's same origin policy is very similar to js.   Both of their policies are listed in part 2 of Google's browser secuirty handbook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be honest I think what you are describing is impossible.  Correct me if i am wrong but this seems like a violation of the same origin policy.   This is the "de-facto Holdy-Grail"  paper of what browsers are allowed to do:
http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Main
Make sure to read section 2.

***EDIT:**  ClickJacking is an attack that bypasses aspects of the same origin policy in un-patched web browsers.  Trying to prevent all attacks that can come from unpatched browsers is a massive undertaking epically considering that person is most likely already hacked and apart of a BotNet. If you are really concerned about vulnerable web browsers I recommend blocking IE6 and below.

Answer (score 2):

On IE8 you have http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/01/27/ie8-security-part-vii-clickjacking-defenses.aspx (So a site or a page that did not want to be iframe would set response header X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY). I also tested this with Firefox 3.5.x at some point and it worked.

Otherwise the linked page (http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/preventing-frame-busting-and-click-jacking-ui-redressing/) pretty accurately describes the issue and how many major sites deal with this today for some subset of their pages since a large number of users still are on IE6, etc.

Comment: This vulnerability affects web browsers and thats where the patch should be.   Trying to stop every vulnerability that affects IE6 is a massive undertaking,  especially because that person is probably a member of a botnet anyway.   If you are really concerned just block IE6 users,  most major sites are dropping support for them anyway.

Comment: Won't disagree about IE6 users. For some sites on this specific issue:1) Site may decide users must have js enabled and so a solution that works across browsers *before* IE8 option is fine.
2) Clickjacking is old and have not seen massive uptick because attackers continue to use phishing, XSS and along with malware remain more serious.
3) Is Opt-in per page. If you have control over webserver you could add this by default to response header (is compat). Would like better soln from browsers. 
4) Non 1E-8, Firefox 3.0+ form large %/no. and business do not want to forgo revenue from these users.

Comment: Adding to prev. comment. If not subject to constraints listed in my previous comment, make use of these options (in answer) and don't support IE6. I don't think IE7 or Safari support these options either.