# onbeforeunload dilemma: iframe breaking vs. annoying message on refresh/back buttons click

Tags: iframe, refresh, onbeforeunload, back-button

I'm implementing a search service called [*SearchInsideOut*](http://www.searchinsideout.com/). 
This search service simply replaces web page results by full web pages (Yes, I used `iframe`).

The problem I have to deal with is iframe-breaking pages.
The promising solution I found is using `onbeforeunload` to let users decide whether to stay or leave my site.
But this also creates another annoying behavior.
When users click other links in my site, `onbeforeunload` will also be triggered.

Fortunately, I could solve this case by placing `window.onbeforeunload=null` in the onclick event of those links of my site.
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to detect external events like clicking "refresh/back" buttons.
What should I do to solve this difficulty?

All suggestions and comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to worry not only about "frame-busting" sites, but also about "frame-busting-buster-busting" sites (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed - just to get a glimpse of what the other side in this armed conflict is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Take as example this site. Try to refresh the page after u typed some text answering to a post. You will see that the page it will ask you to continue ur work or exit. Make another test without answering to a post, just refresh, you will see that the confirm will not showed, because the site is making a test if the "answer" is empty or not.
Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function closeIt()
{
  var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
  if(mytext != "")
     return "Any string value here forces a dialog box to \n" + 
         "appear before closing the window.";
}
window.onbeforeunload = closeIt;
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

So it's up to u to decide when the box will show or not. Visit also [Microsoft Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(v=VS.85).aspx) to understand when and how `onbeforeunload` works