# Scripted iFrame loads contents over current page instead of within an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, location

I'm trying to load a webpage into an iFrame while keeping a content bar on top, but for some pages that I try to load into the iFrame the contents is loaded as if I navigated to that page.

I use the following code to dynamically load an iframe:

```
$('#my_iFrame').attr("src","http://www.nytimes.com/2010/03/26/opinion/26ryan.html");
```

It looks like there is a script on these pages that checks to see if it is being loaded into an iframe and changes the document.location to it's own url if so.

Is there any way around a hack like this so that I can load that site into an iFrame?  Maybe some way to protect the value of window.location?

Comment: I'd be interested if anyone has a solution for this.  The only way that I can see getting around this (especially for pages on separate domains) is to pre-parse the page and all JS content on your own server before delivering it to the client to remove any references to frame breaking code.  But this is likely too expensive and too complicated for most implementations.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Comment: @Alohci Thanks for the reference!  I was hoping there would be a simpler way than the intercepting tactic used there.  It seems there are a lot more ways to bust out of iframes then to keep iframes from busting out.

Answer (score 1):

By Googling, I found this:

```
<script>
function StopLoading()
{
if (!document.all)
{
window.stop();
}
else
{
window.document.execCommand('Stop');
}
}
</script>

<iframe onload="StopLoading()" src="http://www.someaddress.com">
```

However, it seems it does not work if it is in a different domain.
can you try it for a page on same domain and a different domain?

source: http://www.steadyhealth.com/Web_Hosting_Anti_Frame_Breaker_solution_t53346.html