# How can I prevent the subframe from changing "top.location.href "

Tags: javascript

There are some pages have such javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
if (top.location != location)
top.location.href = self.location;
</script>
```

If I have a web page with a frame, linked to those pages, when they loaded, the url of the browser will be changed to their urls. I don't want this, what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame-busting busting can be achieved (as explained [here, on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)), but it's an endless spiral of busters-busting-busters...

I for one advice against forcing frame-busting sites to be framed. It has some bad karma feel about it.

Answer (score 0):

Support for the X-Frame header to prevent framing is in most of the big browsers currently.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options