# What do you mean by http://server-which-responds-with-204.com?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I was reading this article : [Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)

I was wondering what it was ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just any URL that will always return back an [HTTP 204 status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_204#2xx_Success), indicating:

> The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content.

Comment: as you know this is for frame busting..So what should i put instead of "http://server-which-responds-with-204.com"...the url to which my page is redirecting to ??

Comment: Are you trying to write a frame buster? That code is part of a frame buster buster, e.g. it stops frame busters from working.

Comment: var prevent_bust = 0
window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ }
setInterval(function() {
  if (prevent_bust > 0) {
    prevent_bust -= 2
    window.top.location = 'http://mysite.com'
  }
}, 1)

Comment: The problem is that it keeps redirecting to mysite..but i just want it to stop..what do i do ?

Comment: If you're trying to write a frame buster _buster_, whatever server you're using in place of `http://server-which-responds-with-204.com` _needs to always reply with an **HTTP 204** status code_. That means "No Content." That said, if people don't want you iframing their site, why not respect that?

Comment: Well,I want to know the alternative :D