# Iframe not displaying some pages

Tags: php, html, iframe

Having issues displaying some websites within iframes.
[Live example of code](http://www.bourkewebdesign.com/testing_platform/fyp/ipad/page.php?id=stackoverflow#1)

This one works.

```
  <article class='nobackground'>
    <iframe src='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<?php echo $myid ?>'></iframe>
  </article>
```

This one does not display. (neither will youtube, google or facebook, however static html seems to display fine)

```
   <article class='nobackground'>
    <iframe src='http://www.google.ie/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=679&q=<?php echo $myid ?>'></iframe>
  </article>
```

CSS used:

```
 iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 620px;
      background: white;
      border: 1px solid rgb(192, 192, 192);
      margin: -1px; 
 }

 article.fill iframe {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border-radius: 10px;
      -o-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      z-index: -1;
 }
```

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3838600/250517) for explanation of X-Frame-Option header

Comment: Erm... why did you do a `<body style='display: none'>`? _"Nothing to see here, move along...."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google and many others forbid iframing of content through both Javascript (using top.location to detect current framing) and the X-Frame-Option header mention by Grzegorz Grzybek (which forbids framing for compliant browsers).

If you want to capture content you'll have to write a work-around page that does a file_get_content() or cURL call to fetch the code of the page and modify the code slightly (make URLs absolute, remove unwanted scripts) and then echo the code onto a local page.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iframe Google or other sites because of their X-Frame-Options sent through with the header. Your browser respects this and refuses to show the page you are trying to link.