# How can i read a HTML file and display the content in GWT with its css and Javascripts

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I just want to read a HTML file and display its content in a GWT widget. Already I have done it but i'm not getting its css and javascripts. So can anyone help me to get the content with its css and javascripts?

I tried the following code,

```
public class FrameExample implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {

    Frame frame = new Frame("http://www.google.com/");
     RootPanel.get().add(frame);
   }
}
```

I got a rectangular box only. But I don't get the expected result. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget everything I said, you can get the answerer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862755/iframe-not-displaying-some-pages)! 
([Iframe not displaying some pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862755/iframe-not-displaying-some-pages))

Basically: google has a mechanism to detect if it is not hosted in a iframe. This of course raises the question why they us it in their examples.....

BTW: a site like `http://en.wikipedia.com` works.

Comment: Stefan,

Yes http://en.wikipedia.com is working. But i need to view a HTML file in my local system.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance, Gnik

Comment: you can simple write "Frame frame = new Frame(YOURPAGE);" where YOURPAGE is a html page located inside your war folder.

Comment: Stefan, Don't mistake me. Actually my html page is out of my application. So it would not be inside the war folder. I gave the path of the file. Eventhough i got 404 error. Please help me.

Comment: well the most common mistak in that regard is using "\" instead of "/".... have you checked that this is correct. Are you shure the path is correct (have you tested it in with the command line?)

Comment: Stefen, Actually my html file is in the Desktop of my computer. I'm using a Linux machine. So I gave the path "/root/Desktop/fileName.html". Is it correct? Can you help me?

Comment: no, it has to be relativ to your root directory see here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_path

Comment: Stefan, In GWT how can i get the relative path? Since java.io.File is not supported by GWt compiler.

Comment: this has nothing to do with java.io. lets say your FrameExample.html is under /root/Desktop/FrameExample/war/FrameExample.html. the relative pat to your "/root/Desktop/fileName.html" page would be "../../fileName.html/" the "../" means that you move one folder back to get the right path.

Comment: Stefan, My file is in the path /root/Desktop/HTMLFiles/fileName.html. I followed the way what you have told. Eventhough i'm getting 404. Since http://localhost:8080/ is automatically appended with the file path.