# stop loading iframe and redirect parent window if user has not logged in

Tags: php, iframe

I have a web page, which can open a `Target PHP URL` in same domain in an IFRAME lightbox when user clicks a link. Inside the target URL, If "user logged in check" fails, how can I stop opening the IFRAME and redirect the parent window to login page?

or rather, open the Iframe only if user has logged in. Else, redirect the parent window to login page.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `if $user_logged_in === false {echo $redirect header} else {print $body_contents}`

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I tried that, but the redirect is opening in the iframe. (background info: I am using prettyPhoto lightbox to open the iframe)

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838600/how-useful-is-the-x-frame-options-header-in-protecting-against-malicious-framing

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I had tried header("X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY"); too. But the iframe opens blank. I guess I cant stop a client side action from a following server side test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is all the same domain and you're not concerned about a JS solution you could deliver a page like this in the iframe if the user fails the login check.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>You are not logged in...</title>
</head>
<body onload="parent.location.href='REDIRECT_LOCATION'"></body>
</html>
```

Swap out REDIRECT_LOCATION for the location you want the parent window to redirect to.