# prevent break out of iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have a iframe in my webpage (facebook like etc.). can i prevent a break out from this iframe?

I did not the iframe can data be read at my session / forms etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about security: No need. An iframe containing an external page can not read sessions, or submit forms, in the parent page. The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents that.

Other than that: Preventing frame busting is a complicated task. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed) for some of the complexities, and a working code example for a "frame buster buster".