# HTML <title> on a redirected site managed with Plesk not displaying correctly

Tags: html, redirect, title, plesk

I have a site that I have 5 separate domains bought for. The Plesk Panel is set up so that one is the main domain and the other 4 redirect to this.

The problem I have is that if you go to the site via the main domain, the site’s title tag (`<title>""</title>`) displays as I have set it to, but if you visit the site via one of the redirections, it simply displays as the URL.

How can this be fixed so that the proper `<title>` displays no matter how the site is accessed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you frame-forwarded the other domains. First, unless you have a reason, this is a bad idea for SEO and many other things. You may want to select the standard redirection.

Nevertheless, if you must use it that way, open up the `httpdocs` directory for each redirected domain. You will see `index.html` files in which the iframe redirection is done. Just set their `<title>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Your host may be using frames on the redireciton-page, giving you frames on the page you've been redirected to. If this is the case, you could use a [frame-busting script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed/959036#959036).