# How to block pop-up coming from iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, popup, onunload

I'm embedding page that has an exit pop-up. When you close the page, it automatically launches a pop-up window.

**How to disable pop-ups coming from the iframe on exit?**

Comment: Parhaps you should elaborate on your question

Comment: Don't embed pages which have behavior you don't like.

Comment: he is asking a legitimate question... 
"don't embed code with undesirable behaviour" is a bad answer

Let me see.... how do you code this or that.... well don't code it.. become a plumber... there problem solved....


I have the same  problem... and I don't have the luxury of telling my boss something like... well we just don't embed it.... 

Paul.. did you ever solve this problem...???

Comment: @John - please see the answer by @Piskvor - this gives sensible reasons why this *just won't work*. If your boss can't accept reality, then your boss is a fool.

Answer (score 11):

Quite an old ask, but I thought I'd offer a newer solution since this is the top result in google.

If you want to block an iframe from opening windows, you can use the new HTML5 "sandbox" attribute on your iframe.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

This should keep it from doing anything (except running javascript which may be required for the page to function correctly):

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="your/url/here"></iframe>
```

Comment: This might also be helpful related to sandbox attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588472/how-to-block-pop-up-banner-ads-and-video-ads-in-iframe

Answer (score 10):

If you are wanting to block something like POP up ads or something coming from a website you are showing in an IFRAME - it's fairly easy.

Make a **framefilter.php** and **javascriptfilter.php** which your iframe points to.
You can modify it to meet your needs such as the onload blah blah and etc.
But as/is - it's been working fine for me for quite a while. Hope it helps.

Replace your standard IFRAME HTML with this:

```
    <IFRAME SRC="http://www.yourdomainhere.com/framefilter.php?furl=http://www.domainname.com" WIDTH=1000 HEIGHT=500>
If you can see this, your browser doesn't 
understand IFRAMES. However, we'll still 
<A HREF="http://www.domainname.com">link</A> 
you to the page.
</IFRAME>
```

**Framefilter.php**

```
        <?php

//Get the raw html.
$furl=trim($_GET["furl"]);
$raw = file_get_contents($furl);

$mydomain="http://www.yourdomainhere.com/";

//Kill anoying popups.
$raw=str_replace("alert(","isNull(",$raw);
$raw=str_replace("window.open","isNull",$raw);
$raw=str_replace("prompt(","isNull(",$raw);
$raw=str_replace("Confirm: (","isNull(",$raw);

//Modify the javascript links so they go though a filter.
$raw=str_replace("script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"","script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"".$mydomain."javascriptfilter.php?jurl=",$raw);
$raw=str_replace("script src=","script src=".$mydomain."javascriptfilter.php?jurl=",$raw);

//Or kill js files
//$raw=str_replace(".js",".off",$raw);

//Put in a base domain tag so images, flash and css are certain to work.
$replacethis="<head>";
$replacestring="<head><base href='".$furl."/'>";
$raw=str_replace($replacethis,$replacestring,$raw);

//Echo the website html to the iframe.
echo $raw;

?>
```

**javascriptfilter.php**

```
<?php

//Get the raw html.
$jurl=trim($_GET["jurl"]);
$raw = file_get_contents($jurl);

//Note, if trickyness like decode detected then display empty.
if(!preg_match("decode(", $raw)){

//Kill anoying popups.
$raw=str_replace("alert(","isNull(",$raw);
$raw=str_replace("window.open","isNull",$raw);
$raw=str_replace("prompt(","isNull(",$raw);
$raw=str_replace("Confirm: (","isNull(",$raw);

//Echo the website html to the iframe.
echo $raw;

}

?>
```

Comment: You should replace too `isNaN(` cause `isNull()` is not defined.

Comment: Your replacement should consider a case with spaces between the func name and brackets. will be better to use: `$raw=preg_replace("#alert[ ]{0,}\\(#i","isNaN(",$raw);`

Comment: Your preg_match is not valid. Should be: `if(empty(preg_match("#decode\\(#i", $raw))) {`

Comment: Which one better, use this solution or whether to use iframe sanbox tag?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible.

- first (and most importantly), if the iframe is in a different domain, you can't change its DOM - such as the onunload handlers. If this is the case, the other two issues are moot.
- second, even if you could, you'd have to remove the listener in some way. If the listener is loaded via window.onunload, that would be simple; otherwise, not so much.
- third, in the long term this would lead to the same arms race as the [frame-busting-busters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)

The only possibility I see is non-technical in nature: check with whoever runs that site inside the iframe if they could make a special page for you, one without such onunload popup. In most cases, either

- a) some special arrangement can be made (although not always for free), or
- b) removing the functionality would be a violation of the ToS, in which case you'd have to look for someone else providing similar functionality, without the pop-ups (and realistically, most services have more than a single provider)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this *is* possible. Well at least in many cases. Often, the code in the iframe will be running something like `top.window.open(...)` to open a pop-up. You can redefine the window.open method so it still exists, but doesn't open a window. E.g.:

`
window.alias_open = window.open;

window.open = function(url, name, specs, replace) {
  // Do nothing, or do something smart...
}
`

If you still want some pop-ups to open, you can whitelist urls within the body of `window.open`, and call `alias_open` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the sandbox attribute on the IFrame element should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work but you could try double Iframing. Iframe the site in a free blogger account, then iframe the blogger account with a delay loading code. so the popup will occur before the page is loaded let me know if it works.

Answer (score -10):

**Use a modern browser** - they all come with decent pop-up blocking capabilities

Comment: I'm sorry - why the down vote?  You want to know how to disable pop-ups - using a modern browser disables these

Comment: In that case don't be embedding code which has undesirable behaviour