# How to prevent pop-ups that coming from embedded video player

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, video, popup

I have embedded videos(JW Player) on my website and they are producing pop-ups.

I detected a javascript code block inside of iframes:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
                            vc.pu_url = 'http://www.website.com';
                vc.cookie.id = 'vhs_pu_1035_8158';
                vc.language_id = '1';
                                vc.ad_type_id = '3';
                                                vc.pu_trigger_click = '2';
                                vc.pu_default_trigger_click = 'FIRST';
                                    vc.show_top_links = true;
                            vc.report_url = 'http://videos.website.com/player/report_video/s26rf9cqrgms3e6ntks5cqp9d7/5328/8158/1';
                vc.report_msg.success = 'This video was reported with success.';
                vc.report_msg.reason_empty = 'The Reason field is required.';
                vc.report_msg.email_invalid = 'The Email field must contain a valid email address.';
                vc.report_msg.comment_empty = 'The Comment field is required.';
                            vc.allow_ad_block = '1';

                                </script>
```

I tried to edit and delete this block from Chrome's developer tools. Nevertheless video player still producing pop-ups.

So how can I prevent this issue?

I can provide more information and code if necessary. Thx! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4955934/3602947

Comment: I looked these kind of questions but there are no any accepted answers and low ups. For example the answer that you suggested has only 1 up.