# Remove POP up in Iframe

Tags: javascript, php

When I put an Iframe in my website (contain video) when someone click on the Iframe that contain video a pop up ads show. How I can disable that or remove it and get a clean Iframe without pop up ads
I have already try this 
[How to block pop-up coming from iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461282/how-to-block-pop-up-coming-from-iframe)

Comment: Hello, Have you found a way around this question? I am facing the same issue today and I need an answer

Answer (score 3):

You can sandbox your iframe:

```
<iframe src="pageURL" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"></iframe>
```

This does not include `allow-popups` which'll block popups.

Comment: But with this parameters the video in the iframe can be play

Comment: as long as it itself is not a popup

Comment: the video give me this message : hlsjs: Video file not found

Answer (score 0):

Adding this attribute to your iframe should work just fine "**sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin**"