# How to block pop-up, banner ads and video ads in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe

I'm embedding video that has an exit pop-up banner ads and video ads. When you 
anywhere in video then popups open automatic or how to click on **X** icon to close banner ad.

```css
.iframe{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe">
   <iframe width="1000" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Sb_60g3u1LU" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I am using other third party websites to host videos like vidzi.tv & openload.co and these sites are full with pop ups and banner ads in video player.

Answer (score 20):

You can add `sandbox` attribute in your iframe. Only the values you add to the attribute will be allowed. Any value you do not add in the `sandbox` attribute will not be allowed by browser.

Sandbox attribute has following values:

```
allow-forms
allow-pointer-lock
allow-popups
allow-same-origin
allow-scripts
allow-top-navigation
```

I have modified your code to include sandbox option, but have NOT added `allow-popups`, so popups will not be allowed in this iframe.

```html
<div class="iframe">
   <iframe sandbox = "allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation" width="1000" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Sb_60g3u1LU" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

You can find more about sandbox attribute [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp). Please note that this attribute is new in HTML5.

Comment: @values where to add this value? Css section or have to create other page?

Comment: You have to added one of the above mentioned option in the iframe tag. Like I showed in the code example in my above answer.

Comment: but this is not work. i tested with this video. and i still get ads https://www.youtube.com/embed/nmd8_8UiYHE

Comment: sry. this is work for blocking popup on openload. thanks man. sry for misunderstood `<div class="iframe">
   <iframe sandbox = "allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation " width="1000" height="600" src="http://openloadmovies.tv/" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>` i will not get any popup from that website. damn.. how can i miss this attribute

Comment: Please mark my response and Answer if it satisfied your question. Thanks.

Comment: @waqashsn sorry to say but this code is not working on all video hosting sites.

Comment: Can you please show me an example with jsbin or something similar. I want to see what kind of ads are still appearing, as there are a few types that you will be unable to block since they appear inside the content, like the ads in YouTube videos. They are not exactly popups so my answer does not relate to that.

Comment: Doesn't work for openload, they have a mechanism against this :(

Comment: Important to note that this will work on mobile browsers but will still show the 'cannot embed while sandboxed' error on desktop

Comment: @lakam99 I am receiving "remove sandbox attributes ..." which is the same as you mentioned. Any way around it?

Comment: For me doesnt work.error after embeding says "remove sandbox atribute from iframe".

Answer (score 2):

I used `sandbox` function in this code on my Streaming Site where i `Embed` 3rd Party `iframe` and they also have `sandbox` protection check but for that iv'e added `removeAttribute` in my `JS` so if you change `src` of the `iframe` from some other `button` you can click this button to add `sandbox` attribute to your `iframe` or you can also add the `click function` in your code where you get your iframe successfully.

```
//JS
window.onload = function(){
    var button = document.getElementsByName("sandbox")[0]
    var iframe = document.getElementsByName("framez")[0]
    button.addEventListener('click',sndbx,false);

    function sndbx(){
    var nibba = document.getElementById("framez").src;
    if(iframe.sandbox == 'allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation'){
    document.getElementById("framez").removeAttribute("sandbox"); 
    }
    frames['framez'].location.href=nibba;
    iframe.sandbox = 'allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation';
    }
}
```

```
<!--HTML-->
<button name="sandbox">SandBox</button>
<iframe name="framez" id="framez" src="YOUR_SOURCE" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: .location.href is reading undefined? is this line important?

Answer (score 1):

Use sandbox after loading Iframe so if someone blocks the sandbox it will still work.

```
<script>
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var frame of frames) {
    frame.setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-pointer-lock allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-forms");
}
</script>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. the sandbox attribute is added but I still get popup ads.

Comment: doesn't work for me too