# Is there a way to block ads from an embed?

Tags: javascript, html, web, video-streaming

so currently I'm having a embed from another site and ads are popping up in my site,
how do I block them?

some code

```
<embed id="embed" src="http://example.com/mp4.mp4">
```

Comment: What kind of embed are we talking about? An `<iframe>`? And are the ads only shown within this embed or also outside of it?

Comment: so im currently using the <embed> tag and the ads are shown outside the embed

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48648933/15354370

Comment: @Tanay I've tried this option but IDK if embed has an attribute called sandbox,
im using this element to clear somethings up https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_embed.asp

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.