# How do I disable chat box and popups from iframe content I am displaying

Tags: iframe

I would like to share some useful information using iframes on my website but I don't want popups or chat boxes to show up inside the iframe. Is there a way to suppress these?

Comment: Possibly duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461282/how-to-block-pop-up-coming-from-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Just use paid service subscribe to that service if its youtube or Vimeo use a premium account those accounts have options to turn of those pop up. Please give enough information .