# remove ads from iframe link

Tags: javascript, html, ads

how to remove pop_ups ads from below link

```
\<iframe width="640" height="480" src="//mixdroop.bz/e/wn3meepqt9rmd" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"\>\</iframe\>
```

I try sandbox code but it didn't work

Comment: you can't control what some other site does

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to block pop-up coming from iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461282/how-to-block-pop-up-coming-from-iframe)