# Disable the javascript and meta tag from other HTML page by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have one HTML files on one server and two files on different server, as below:

**a.html - server 1**

```
<html><head></head><body><iframe src="http://server2/b.html"></iframe></body></html>
```

**b.html - server 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */if (top == self ||  parent != top ||  document.location.hostname != document.domain) {  top.location.replace("c.html");}/* ]]> */</script>
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" id="myworld" class="no_js"> 
<head><meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */if (top == self ||  parent != top ||  document.location.hostname != document.domain) {  top.location.replace("c.html");}/* ]]> */</script><noscript> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=b.html?st=1" /> </noscript>
</head><body>text is here</body></html>
```

**c.html - server 2**

```
<html><head></head><body>Please visit later.</body></html>
```

When I open `http://server1/a.html`, I am redirected to `http://website2/c.html` because it uses JavaScript and a meta tag for redirecting if the host is different.

What I want to do is: I don't want `b.html` to run its JavaScript at all for redirecting and the meta tag refresh to `c.html`.

How can code `a.html` to render `b.html` in my iframe only? So it should disable `b.html`'s javascript and meta tag.

Comment: This question may help you: [Frame Buster Buster … buster code needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)

Comment: Interesting hack there, but: I'm really not sure we should be advising people how to disable frame-busting code. Even leaving the moral issues aside, their website will suddenly break if the frame-busting code ever gets updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like server 2 is a owned by a third-party and you have no control over it. Unfortunately the javascript you can see there is a 'frame breakout' script which is specifically designed to prevent the page from being embedded in a iframe, as you are trying to do.

One way around is to make an HTTP request directly from your web server to load page `b`, and then strip out the javascript and include it as part of your page.

Edit: You should really ask the other site's permission, as you are basically redistributing their content if you do this.

Comment: Yes, that is right, but i have a question for you; how can i strip out if i can load up the a code in server 2? I can't touch the file of b.html and c.html, but i want to do only with a.html.

Comment: You can't do it from Javascript - you'd have to download page `b` on your own web server for this to work. You would need some server-side code (e.g. Python, ASP.NET) running on your own server.

Comment: Glad it works. Do click on the big tick if you feel I answered your question :)