# Stop other websites iframing?

Tags: php, html, security

We run an online service (aka a script) and we have discovered a few websites over the past few weeks putting our script on their site via iframe.

What precautions can we take to stop other people putting our site into theirs via iframe?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it matter if your "script" is on their site? Doesn't your service have your site's name in it?

Comment: It does but when they use CSS to hide all of our website except the input box, it kinda annoys us.

Comment: Wait, they're using CSS to hide just the input box?  That sounds like it's a UI redressing attack.

Comment: No, they are attaching a class to the iframe and then making the iframe position itself so it only shows our input box on the page. In other words they are making the iframe hide everything else on our website using CSS. For example: top:-300px; 
left:-139px; 
width:1200px; 
height:1000px;

Answer (score 2):

A more global solution would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (top.location != location) {
        top.location.href = document.location.href ;
    }
</script>
```

Place it on the top of your page (inside the "head" tag).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Answer (score 1):

On modern browsers, send the header `X-Frame-Options` with the value `DENY`.  If it's a recent enough browser, it'll obey the header and tell the iframe to pack sand.

Comment: There's also the same origin option too, so at least your own site can iframe its own content if it wants.

Comment: @Zimzat - same-origin should not be used unless explicitly needed - you never know if an attacker has managed to insert malicious content onto the server.