# how to disable script in iframe to control the parent?

Tags: javascript, iframe

i have set up a demo which use iframe to include an target webpage for people to add some widgets on it,

but some website has script to detect if it is in iframe,

and if true, they use parent.window.location to redirect the parent's url,

so how can i disable this behavior?

or can you guys tell me any other ways to do it

Comment: If it's properly implemented, you can't disable the behaviour. Most sites employ it for security reasons. Somewhat related: [Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/958997)

Comment: Just an idea (dont know if it will work): try to set ifrm.parent=NULL therefore it cannot access to your main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable scripting at browsers by setting `designMode="On"` at the IFrame element. This doesn't work in Chrome, though.

There's no reliabel way to circumvent *frame busting scripts*. The website maintainer can send the `X-Frame-Options: deny` header, which causes most recent browsers to refuse loading the content in a frame.

Comment: @jyf1987 I quote my answer: `"There's no reliable way to circumvent frame busting scripts"`. I believe that that is exactely what you were looking for, so the `Accept` mark is correctly applied, in this case. If someone posts an answer to your question, which is close, but not close enough, don't hesitate adding a comment to request for an additional explanation. But **avoid [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) ;)**

Comment: thank you for refer me to the link chameleon questions, i have gave it my own suggestions

Comment: @jyf1987 I mentioned chameleon questions, not because you've posted one, but to make you aware of the existence of these. Your intents are **good**, but your wording needs to improve. Remember, Stack Overflow is **not a forum**, but a **Question & Answer** site. In a forum, it is possible to start off with a vague question, and explain your intents, based on replies. At this site, partcipants are expected to post clear messages. Have a look at **Meta: ["Guidelines to ask real questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122765/guidelines-to-ask-real-questions)**