# Prevent javascript from popping out of frame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I making a tool where a user has to quickly sort throo a heap of websites
to determine weather they are fit for a particular purpose.
I load the websides inside and iframe. All fine here but
some sites have javascript code that makes them pop out of frames.
Now is there a way to prevent that ?
i'v tried onbeforeunload , it worked for a while , but it seems even that isn't working anymore.

Comment: did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)? I know you said onbeforeunload but it's a bit vague

Comment: i'v sorted it out with onbeforeunload , it's kind of annoying with the popup but it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really - if website has script like `top.location = "mypagehere";` then the other page will load outside the frame, or if it has `alert()` alert will show up.

The only way around this is using server side language to read the contents of those remote sites then put only the contents, without any scripts, inside your own placeholders.

If you have server side language at your disposal edit your question and put comment here so that we can guide you further.