# Can you beat a frame breaker?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I haven't been able to find much of an answer yet, so I'm just going to ask.

How difficult would it be to stop a frame breaker from working - or even just ignore it?

Comment: As an end user you could just disable javascript execution...

Comment: But can somone prevent the beating of a framebreaker? This would be a framebreakerbeaterbreaker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [Jeff's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed):

As it turns out, **your frame-busting code can be busted**, [as shown here](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/preventing-frame-busting-and-click-jacking-ui-redressing/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prevent_bust = 0  
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ }  
    setInterval(function() {  
      if (prevent_bust > 0) {  
        prevent_bust -= 2  
        window.top.location = 'http://server-which-responds-with-204.com'  
      }  
    }, 1)  
</script>
```

This code does the following:

- increments a counter every time the browser attempts to navigate away from the current page, via the `window.onbeforeonload` event handler
- sets up a timer that fires every millisecond via `setInterval()`, and if it sees the counter incremented, changes the current location to a server of the attacker's control
- that server serves up a page with HTTP status code **204**, which does not cause the browser to navigate anywhere

Answer (score 6):

This is the solution to your problem, I hope it helped!

`<iframe src="URL" sandbox="allow-scripts" width="100%" height="100%" scroll="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>`