# Redirects within an iframe using php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Say i'm using an iframe to display some other website on my website. But if the site displayed has a redirect that redirects to some other pages on its domain, the redirects causes the whole browser to redirect to the other site which i do not want it to happen.

Is it possible to make the redirect appear inside the iframe instead of having the whole browser redirecting to another page?

Comment: server side redirect will happen in the iframe, seems more its making a top.location.href in javascript. maybe to prevent being displayed in an frame? :)

Comment: Sounds like an iframe buster. Probably shouldn't be displaying their website on your own then.

Comment: Here's the Wikipedia article on the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller

Comment: Also, here's a link to a similar question. Although, as Dave Chen said, you ought to avoid these types of situations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898503/can-you-beat-a-frame-breaker

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5 the [iframe sandbox](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) attribute was added. At the time of writing this [works on Chrome, Safari, Firefox and recent versions of IE and Opera](http://caniuse.com/iframe-sandbox) but does pretty much what you want:

```
<iframe src="url" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

If you want to allow top-level redirects specify `sandbox="allow-top-navigation"`.

Comment: Note that this essentially makes the click void, it does not redirect within the iframe itself.