# How can I stop loading a web page if it is equiped with frame-buster buster?

Tags: javascript, iframe, frame, x-frame-options

How can I stop loading a web page if it uses a frame-buster buster as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997), or an even stronger `X-Frame-Options: deny` like stackoverflow.com? I am creating a web application that has the functionality of loading external web pages into an `<iframe>` via javascript, but if the user accidentally steps on to websites like google.com or stackoverflow.com, which have a function to bust a frame-buster, I just want to quit loading. In stackoverflow.com, it shows a pop up message asking to disable the frame and proceed, but I would rather stop loading the page. In google, it removes the frame without asking. I have absolutely no intent of click jacking, and at the moment, I only use this application by myself. It is inconvinient that every time I step on to such sites, the frames are broken. I just do not need to continue loading these pages.

**Edit**

Seeing the answers so far, it seems that I can't detect this before loading. Then, is it possible to load the page in a different tab, and then see if it does not have the frame-buster buster, and then if it doesn't, then load that into the `<iframe>` within the original tab?

**Edit 2**

I can also acheive the header or the webpage as an html string through the script language (Ruby) that I am using. So I think I indeed do have access to the information before loading it into an `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to detect this before loading the page since the frame busting is done via a header or is triggered via JavaScript as the page is loading.

Answer (score 1):

Without a server backend you won't be able to as you are pretty limited with the amount of tinkering you can do in javascript due to crossdomain policies.

You might want to consider creating some sort of a blacklist for URLs to stay away from...

Comment: Blacklist may be the last resort to do.