# HTML5 domain locking?

Tags: php, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I've got a project where we're creating a dynamic html5 based video player with a bunch of Ajax controls and features. The intention is that this player will be used by other domains. Our old player used flash and could easily domain-lock, but now is there *any* method at all to do domain locking in HTML5?

Keep in mind that's its not just the video itself, we're also wanting to load html content for our ajax based controls. It seems like iframe is the obvious choice for this but then there's no way to do domain locking.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please define "domain locking" in this context. It could mean several things...

Comment: what HTML and JS you release to the "wild" will always be read and reverse engineered - because the source, unlike flash, is in a very readable view. even youtube videos, no matter how they hide the url, and other parameters, the video url is still captured by tools like firebug.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Comment: @DaveRandom By "domain locking", I mean preventing our html5 player from loading on non-whitelisted domains that we would keep a list of internally.

Comment: @fskreuz we're not concerned with protecting the content. We just want to restrict the player itself from loading on non-approved domains. We certainly not concerned with our js or html code being revealed :)

Comment: @Citizen what i meant was exactly that. no matter how youtube hides all parameters,  it may not be in the source, it will be revealed and reversed. Now, you are moving to HTML, a language with source visible as day, one can just copy your source, remove your locking-code, and use somewhere else.

Comment: @c69 That 'iframe busting' method is only intended for blocking 'all' external access. We want to do domain locking against an inernal whitelist, meaning only domains x, y, and z can load it.

Comment: @fskreuz I guess a different way of wording is that we're not looking for a perfect solution. Even if all we can do is display a warning saying that 'this player is being shown on an invalid site' would be good enough. All we need to be able to do is detect that its on a non-whitelisted site, not do source protection or anything like that.

Comment: ..well, in that case iframe, framebuster and checking http referrer should do the job ? As most regular people would not be spoofing referrer, and thus you can detect inappropriate embeds.

Comment: @Citizen how did you do it in flash? i assume you hard-coded the domain to the source. you can't do that in HTML. it's not source protection, it's just that HTML is just readable. anyone could just copy your player's code, remove the locking code, and use the "unlocked" player.

Comment: Have you resolved your situation? I have an idea for you, which will work if a client's website is linking to a js file on your server. If you are still interested, use chat (link at the top) and send me a message. I will see it next time I log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the function above, but its pretty obvious what it's doing, so anyone can just remove the domain lock.

There are services out there that will lock your page to a domain name, I know of two off the top of my head.

[jscrambler.com](https://jscrambler.com) - this is a paid tool, but it might be a bit of an overkill if all you want to do is lock your domain.

[DomainLock JS](https://domainlockjs.com) - this is a free domain locking tool.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for the same thing. But I think I have an answer worked out.
The best way I found sofar is to strip the location.href of its http:// and then check the first few characters for a whitelisted domain. So:

```
    if(checkAllowedDomains())
    {
         initApplication();
    }
    else 
    {
         // it's not the right domain, so redirect them!
         top.location.href="http://www.snoep.at";
    }

    function checkAllowedDomains()
    {
        var allowed_domains=new Array();
        allowed_domains.push("www.snoep.at");
        allowed_domains.push("www.makinggames.nl");
        allowed_domains.push("www.google.com");
        // add whatever domain here!
        var domain=top.location.href;
        domain.replace('http://','');
        var pass=false;
        for(i=0;i<allowed_domains.length;i++)
        {
            var shortened_domain=domain.substr(2,allowed_domains[i].length);
            if(shortened_domain.indexOf(allowed_domains[i])!=-1)
            {
              pass=true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This bit of code checks several allowed_domains, you can easily extend the array.
That is the problem with the code, it's very readable. So, I'd advise you to put it through a js-minimizer to make it less obvious and include it in EVERY js on your page. InitApplication() is a function that starts your page or application.

Because you strip the location of http:// (which may or may not be there) and then checking only for the specific length (including the WWW!) of the allowed domain, you rule out subdomains, that might look like this: google.com.mydomain.com and throw the check of!

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about location.hostname ?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading REFERER header, and if the site isn't blacklisted, don't display player.

Comment: REFERER is not reliable. Any solution using this can break very easily because it will be highly dependent on the client. There is no guarantee that the client will even set this header.