# How to prevent iframe page redirect parent page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

If use iframe to handle some webpage.But some of them just redirect my parent page to theirs.I found this code

> if(self!=top) top.location=self.location;

My question is how to prevent this and make iframe page in my ifrme.

Comment: If the page does not want to be in an iframe, than it should not be there. Search the site, this has been asked a lot.

Comment: You have entered into the ongoing frame-buster-buster war, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No mechanism exists to do what you want to do.  It would be an arms race anyway; if such a technique existed, wouldn't the people who use the code you mention above want to find some way to defeat it?