# iframe loads the external website instead of being an iframe

Tags: iframe

so when i insert the iframe, the page loads to the external website instead, it loads 2 seconds on my webpage before it redirects. I just want it to be an iframe and not redirect to that site, any ideas? Never had this before.

```
<iframe src="http://test.net/" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="5000px" width="757px"></iframe>
```

Comment: another site source just works fine, exept from this site. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites will detect that they're in an iframe and try to break out of it - given that it's a site-specific issue, that sounds likely.

Comment: can the outbreak be prevented?

Comment: I've never done it, but possibly - start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947026/prevent-iframe-from-changing-parent-location