# HTML <iframe> with a link inside

Tags: html, iframe

I have a website A that contains an iframe I. Website B inside iframe I contains the following anchor tag:

```
<a target="_parent" href="myHref">Link desc</a>
```

Without inserting JavaScript code into the anchor tag, how can I make the browser open the link in a new tab?

---

If B is a standalone website (i.e. not inside an iframe), clicking the anchor tag should also open a new tab.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947026/prevent-iframe-from-changing-parent-location

Answer (score 0):

What matters here is the value of your anchor's target attribute. It is currently set to "_parent", which - as the name suggests - will make it open in the parent frame (i.e. website A).

Set `target="_blank"`, and the link will open in a new tab, regardless of website B being inside an iframe or not.

```
<a target="_blank" href="myHref">Link desc</a>
```

More details about the target attribute are available at [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target).