# iframe workaround to load http://www.google.com in a webkit browser

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, iframe

So the latest version of Chrome and maybe Safari too doesn't let you load in iframes inless you're on the same domain for certain websites that don't want to be iframed like google.com.

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" style="width:600px;height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The Error I get in Chrome is..
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Is there a workaround to avoid this error and display the iframe.

From what I read the x-frame stuff is to prevent click jacking via iframe, but I'm not trying to do that I just want to load in the site the way the iframe I thought was supposed to perform.

Is there away around this using PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)

Comment: Also check out this: http://blog.futtta.be/2009/12/02/google-inadvertently-killing-talk-badges-with-x-frame-options/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to bypass this restriction.