# Javascript to disable onload function inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, onload

I have an iframe on my web page, the source url is a remote web page I don't have access to, the problem is that in that iframe body onload event, there is a JS function:

```
 <body onload="if(top!=self) top.location.href=location.href">
```

so that will change my webpage to their webpage url. is there anyway I can use javascript on my web page to disable or rewrite the body onload function in that iframe? I think that is different from the iframe onload event.

Comment: Check out this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Answer (score 0):

The only way to even try to bust this would be to use server-side code (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.) to essentially proxy their page into an iframe that you control. You could grab the source of their document and do a replacement to get rid of their onload event server-side.

You'd want to set up a structure something like:

```
AppFolder
    index.html
    your_iframe.php
```

In your iframe, simply download the contents of the url and do a replacement and echo back out to the browser. There are still a number of issues that you'd have to workout, such as relative resource paths in the iframed document.

Comment: I can make no guarantees that this method will work, however. It's just a theory at this point.