# JavaScript FrameBuster with Allowed Domains

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to write a framebuster that allows specific domains to load the page in an iframe.  If it weren't for cross-domain stuff, I could simply check the top.location.href, but since cross-domain policies prevent this, is there any other way for me to check what domain is trying to load the page in an iframe?

I'm not sure how this guy: [Framebuster with exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056889/framebuster-with-exceptions) was doing it since he says his works, but he is checking against top.location, which isn't allowed cross-domain.

Am I chasing a pipe dream here?

Comment: can you use CSP headers?

Comment: I need to be able to allow un-controlled domains to iframe in the page, such as webtrends.com.