# Checking Third-Party iFrame Content

Tags: javascript, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Frame Buster Buster … buster code needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)

I'm playing around with third-party iframes, trying to learn what I can and can't do.

**One thing I haven't figured out:**

When it comes to loading a third-party iframe, Is there a way to check ahead of loading the page that it does NOT allow its site to be iframed?

In the past, I've noticed that some third-party sites (e.g. NYTimes, etc.) have a JS function that redirects the page if it detects it is being iframed. Is there a way to check that a redirect function like that exists?

**The function typically looks something like this:**

> function deframe(){if (top.location != location) top.location.href =
>   document.location.href;} deframe();

Meanwhile, instead of redirecting, other third-party sites simply load a blank page when iframed (e.g. Google, Twitter). I'm trying to avoid that, too.

Ideally, as my page loads, I'd have a way of realizing in advance that these sites don't allow themselves to be iframed and load something else instead.

Comment: you mean anti frame-busting? **lots** of results on google. and here at [so]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Comment: Thanks for this. Will check it out. I'm hoping to let others load in content in an iframe, but in doing so I'd like to avoid any sites that want to frame-bust me -- I'd just load messaging to the user saying that site XX doesn't allow its page to be iframed, etc.