# How do I prevent a site in a iframe from refreshing the whole site?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have a simple iframe in my website that displays other websites. Users submit their websites and then other users can view that website in an iframe within my website. It works great, but the problem is that there are certain sites that refresh the whole site and the user ends up leaving my site and visits the site in the iframe. How would I prevent this from happening? I don't mind if a user clicks a link and they leave my website, but I don't want them initially leaving my website. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can't be done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Comment: Or you can try the code at the link, should be the best you'll get.

Comment: most people prefer their site not to be framed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But if you dont want them to  leave you can always open that link in another window using the target option.