# Hide referer iFrame

Tags: iframe

My website is www.A.com. In my website I have an iframe which src is www.B.com and I don't own.

I don't want B.com to know that i'm inserting their website in mine through an iframe.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Comment: i don't want an anti-iframe, i just want to hide the referer. I'm inserting an iframe from other website in mine, and i want to hide my domain, 
EDIT: because they can know it right?