# Iframe sources keeps redirecting to url (firefox)

Tags: redirect, iframe

I put url in a frame - it redirects me to that url instead of appearing in the iframe. I bypassed that on chrome by doing so:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts" src="www.example.com"></iframe>
```

On firefox it still keeps me rederecting. Is there an alternative way of `sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts"` for firefox?

Comment: Maybe that the site referenced by the URL uses some sort of *framebusting* technique..

Comment: yeah it does, thats why i need to bypass it or make it not load and not rederect at all

Comment: I know is a silly question but do you have the lastest version of Firefox?

Comment: @user1894929 what is the site that you want to put into iframe? it's hard to bypass framebusting without seeing how they do it..

Comment: haha yeah i was about to write this lol, turns out my firefox is only at 13.0 version, i found that firefox only supports sandbox from version 17.0 and up :)

Comment: The firefox version update thing didnt help, still makes redirects. @Shimon Rachlenko im trying to load this url -> www.delfi.lt

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you are useing "sandbox" but did you tried only with:

```
 <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: yeah i tried it, it redirects to the url (depends on the url ofc). that sandbox code prevented it from making redirects on chrome, on firefox this trick doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely impossible to defeat the *framebusting* code. See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed) and [this study](http://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/framebusting/framebust.pdf) for some more insights.
I tried some of ways described there and they either don't work at all or don't work for the site you mentioned.

Comment: thanks, i tried using methods from that SO thread but nothing seems to have worked for me