# I need to protect my website from iframe. In the same times, i need to iframe by my own sites and some permitted website. How can i do this?

Tags: php, javascript, security, .htaccess, iframe

I need to protect my website from iframe. In the same times, I need to iframe by my own sites and some permitted website. How can I do this?

Every website cannot use iframe until I permit them. I seen it's possible provably by javascript.

See this link to realize the code view-source:http://onlinefreetv.net/test.php/

By this above code I can protect from any iframe but this system has no facility to allow my own site or permitted site to do iframe.

I hope I could described everything to get actual help. Thanks

Comment: Actually i'm not wise on coding. Can you solve this issue? I want to allow iframe by onlinefreetv.net and some allowed site, but all others normal site will redirect to my website if they iframe any link.

Comment: sounds like you are trying to implement fake ad clicks on your site..basically click jacking..:/

Comment: Lets talk on my room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28210/servant

Comment: @Servant he needs 20 rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
if (top.location !== self.location){
    top.location = self.document.location;
}
```

Comment: Note this is [not watertight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed).

Answer (score 0):

You should better try these configuration directives in your *.htaccess* hidden file if it'll work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yoursite\.com$
RewriteRule . /abuse.txt [L]
```

And create an */abuse.txt* file on your file manager with an abuse sentence that you want, such any caution or warning. But make sure that your web hosting account have **Apache HTTP Server** with `mod_rewrite`.