# preventing clickjacking attack by javascript

Tags: javascript, security, clickjacking

Clickjacking is when people trick users into clicking a button they're not supposed to, making them perform a malicious action.

I'm working on a product which, as an option for merchants, provides an iFrame component that can be embedded into a website to make a payment. Signed in users will see a button in the iframe that they can click to perform an important action. This action should only be called when the click is genuinely theirs.

i use this code to prevent clickjacking :

```
if (top == self ||  parent != top ||  document.location.hostname != document.domain) {  top.location.replace("https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/?404");}
```

can someone break into my code ?

note: i don't want to use x-frame-option

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

From an Iframe you cannot really control clicks from the parent, if they click inside the Iframe but another event is watching it, you cannot really prevent it being from a different domain.

But all is not lost, the Iframe itself cannot stop it, but it can be wrapped with something like this. This is assuming jquery, might be best to translate to a native version for your application, in the interest of showing an example I will use jQuery.

```
<div id="i_wrap"><iframe src="SRC"></iframe></div>
<script>
$('#i_wrap').on('click',function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Of course this is not a cure-all, there are still ways around this. You could also use a portion of the new HTML 5 cross document messaging [read here on it](http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/) to do some validation and possible warn the user on an unsafe site (if your iframe gets no message, then you show no button).

Though I have no experience in the cross document messaging methods, and I am sure they probably don't allow different domains (though there may be ways around that, to an extent).

Though this question is not totally clear and I may not be understanding it perfectly, if you update your question with more details I will update my answer to suit.

Comment: thank you for your response ,i will try to clarify more : in the <iframe src="SRC"></iframe> the SRC is using this portion of code if (top == self ||  parent != top ||  document.location.hostname != document.domain) {  top.location.replace("https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/?404");} to prevent loading his content on an iframe on a different domain ,i'am searching a way to bypass this protection to succefuly load this iframe on a diffent domain .some people said to me that is exploitable while there is no x-frame-options but no one gives me a practical bypass.thank you

Comment: One major flaw with client side languages is that the server is not what handles it, it is the client. This is why the browser security protocols are so strict since exploitation would be so easy. Based on what I read from this comment I cannot understand what you are truly asking for. Based on what I read you want to try to prevent a site with your iframe having some JavaScript that might try to catch the click event to your site. So my answer here just disables that as much as possible.