# How to embed affiliate link in a frame?

Tags: html

I am signed up as an affilate for a program, and I would like to embed the site into a regular frame or an iframe so I can provide other information in a navigation bar , but whenever I try to embed using either an iframe or a plain frameset it the page says "This action is not supported"

The link I'm trying to embed is this http://www.solavei.com/graydini/

Any suggestions, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

The affilate web page has some javascript which detects when it's embedded in a frame and displays the error you see:

```
var w=window.location;
var s=window.self.location;
var t=window.top.location;
var p=window.parent.location;
if(s!==w||s!==t||s!==p){window.document.write("This action is not supported.");
```

I don't think there's anything you can easily do to [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed?rq=1) this.