# x-frame-option SAMEORIGIN and clickjacking in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security, iframe, clickjacking

The application had problems with allowing to be loaded into iframe. I have read a lot about it (and clickjacking).
As it is necessary to load a page into the iframe withing the same origin, I have come to the following solution:

Add the following to the global.asax file

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("x-frame-options", "SAMEORIGIN")
```

However, I know that not all browsers support this header. So, I want to add some additional javascript sollution. As I am not expert in javascript, I have found the following sollution:

```
<script>    
    if (self == top) {        
        var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]        
        theBody.style.display = "block"        
    } else {        
        top.location = self.location        
    }    
</script>
```

I know that it could be blocked if the one wants it very  much, however, this makes some extra security.

My question is - 
1) I do not understand the logic of this javascript code (can you give some comments about hte logic)
2) and if this works within SAMEORIGIN (allow iframe loading in the same page, but doesn't allo on other pages)?

**edit:**

I have found another approach that seems clear to me, however, I am not sure if this is more secure than above:

```
<style>html { visibility : hidden }</style>
<script>
    if (self == top ) {
        document.documentElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        top.location = self.location;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`self` is the current page, and if it is equal to `top` which is the outermost framed page then the logic is that it isn't in a frame so everything is OK. If not, it sets the location of the outermost frame to be the current page (`top.location = self.location;`). This is known as "frame buster" code, but there have also been some published "frame buster buster" scripts that break attempts at stopping content being framed, so bear in mind that your JavaScript may not always work.

`x-frame-options` is the way to go, so if you've added that then you should be secure on modern browsers, but you could try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012585/413180) which will display a warning message if a site tries to stop your frame buster from working.

Comment: I know about x-frame-options. Does this "frame buster" code makes some problems if I want frame inside the same page? (SAME ORIGIN)?

Comment: @renathy You could add logic to not bust out of your own frames. You will be able to access and check variables from outside the frame because it is the same origin.

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand your last comment. I do no need accessing or checking any variables. I have exiting applicatin that is not written by me. And I just need to insert into there SECOND code block from my comment (including, html { visibility : hidden }). I wonder if this will make any problems (The application has iframe within itself pointing to the form within this application -so x-frame-options is set to SAMEORIGIN, but also the js code should be inserted if it is not doing any damage).

Comment: If the IFrame is within your page then it depends on the page content and headers of the framed page as to whether it can be framed or not. If the above script is in your page then it will not affect it.

Comment: And which code is better from given - the first one or the second one (with visibility). For me it seems that the second code is more difficult to overcome, because page would be invisible.