# How to prevent an iframe from uniframing itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

We use iframes to showcase designs of websites (with their consent). The problem is, some websites have scripts such as:

```
if (top != self) top.location.replace(self.location.href);
```

This causes the browser to "jump" to their website. How can we suppress these scripts? Is there even a way?

Comment: Related (there may be an answer in there, see "As it turns out, your frame-busting code can be busted...") [Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/958997)

Comment: That's called a frame buster. There are supposedly frame buster busters. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed (I would ask, however, that if you have the site's consent to iFrame it, why are they using frame busters?)

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Turns out that there is also a [page buster buster buster](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/anti-anti-frame-busting/).

Comment: @Tom - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller#Framekiller_killers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found on the **[Wikipedia Article on Framekillers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller)**:

```
var prevent_bust = 0;

// Event handler to catch execution of the busting script.
window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ };

// Continuously monitor whether busting script has fired.
setInterval(function() {
  if (prevent_bust > 0) {  // Yes: it has fired. 
    prevent_bust -= 2;     // Avoid further action.
    // Get a 'No Content' status which keeps us on the same page.
    window.top.location = 'http://server-which-responds-with-204.example.com/';
  }
}, 1);
```

This seems like it would be the most reliable way to go but you'll have to use it and see if your situation fits for this and report back here.  Good luck though.

*PS - there are others on that page if you want to do more research.*