# Javascript line of code in plain english

Tags: javascript

There is this line of code that is on most of our pages that I'm trying to figure out what it's for and if I can remove it.

It looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  if(top!=self){top.location.replace(self.location.href);}
  /*]]>*/
</script>
```

I know it's probably a silly question, but what is this line of script trying to say.  Could this be related to the sign in functionality?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's an iframe buster. If this page gets loaded into an iframe, that line of code attempts to reload that page as the top page in the browser.

Comment: [But keep in mind that there are iframe buster busters.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (top != self) { // if the top frame isn't this window
    top.location.replace( // set the top frame's location
        self.location.href // to this window's location
    );
}
```