# Block my iframe from executing top.location.href inside its javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that loads an iframe with a webpage, but my restriction is that it has to be running under my iframe, and it is not suppose to redirect the parent page to its address by using `top.location.href` javascript function from within the iframe.

Is there anyway to block that `top.location.href = '';` is executed? without having to install any extensions or change the browser settings (since it is viewed by the public through a browser).

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Comment: this might be solution https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange