# Certain sites are not loading in iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I trying to open certain sites in iframe but my browser is not loading those sites. My Source code is

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://www.microsoft.com">
      <p> Your browser does not support iframes. </p>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

This snippet is working fine and it loads microsoft.com in iFrame but when I change src to http://www.amazon.com it does not load amazon.com in iFrame. I am not sure why it is happening and is there any solution available for that.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't show you

> Refused to display 'http://www.amazon.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Because

`it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Please learn more about X-Frame-Options [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)