# Check if current page is frame with javascript

Tags: javascript, frame

I want to check if my current page is in frame and i am doing this. But my browser crashing.I want to work with all browsers. How can i make it work without crashing?
My code

```
if (window.frameElement) {
  //here is my code
}
```

Comment: I would recommend checking out [Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed) or similar SO questions.

Comment: Try to check out window.top.location.href, it has your parent iframe href, so you can compare with current href, (window.top.location.href == window.location.href)

Comment: @RicardoPontual this will working with all browsers ??

Comment: Yes, all modern browsers support:
[link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp)